# How to automap in Nest without writing to the elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Is it possible to leverage the NEST [auto-mapping features](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html) to obtain Nest Property and Type objects without actually writing them into the elastic index via PUT Mapping and Create Index APIs?

For example, I'd like to auto-map this CLR class Company:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and store the elastic mappings into variables like these:

```
Nest.TypeMapping typeCo = null; // for the mapped Company type
Nest.IProperty propCoName = null;  // for the mapped Company Name property
```

but not to write the Company mapping to the index.

I could write to a temp index as a workaround but I suspect this isn't necessary.

Using elasticsearch 5.x and Nest 5.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your goal is to just query and deserialize the Elastic document values via an index that already exists and has a structure that would correlate to your model?

Comment: @MikeMichaels No. I want to serialize .NET objects into Nest (also CLR) data types, but not actually write to an index. Kind of like replace the writing with a NOOP but keep the results of the would-be mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you need, you could take a couple of different approaches

#### Using `PropertyWalker`

```
var walker = new PropertyWalker(typeof(Company), null);   
var properties = walker.GetProperties();
```

will provide the `IProperty` types as are inferred by automapping.

#### Using `TypeMappingDescriptor<T>`

```
var descriptor = (ITypeMapping)new TypeMappingDescriptor<Company>()
    .AutoMap();
```

will provide `IProperty` types in the `.Properties` property inferred from automapping, in addition to any other properties of `ITypeMapping`. Need to use the descriptor here as opposed to `TypeMapping` because the descriptor has the `.AutoMap()` method. Also need to cast to the interface as interface properties are explicitly implemented.